# How to line up floating divs?

Tags: html, css

This might be a simple question, but how do I position the floating divs together?
What I have tried:

```
 <div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post your wished result (a screenshot too) and your code

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good job for floats. Just about any other layout technique (grid, flex, inline-block) would probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a classic case for Flex box: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

All divs are already floated to left, it's just because of the size of text in each box. If you remove some text from first and second div similar to third div, all divs will be inline.

### OR

Add `margin-bottom: 90px;` to the third div; it will solve your problem.

[image: Screenshot of web page showing 6 divs evenly spaced in a 3 x 2 grid.]

Answer (score 0):

Add css to service class:

.services {min-height:400px;}

You can add min-height according your requirement... As you have uneven content in all services block... so you have to give min-height to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    background-color:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>menu one</li>
    <li>menu two</li>
    <li>menu three</li>
    <li>menu four</li>    
<ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add CSS to this class "col-md-4 col-sm-4"  `clear: left;`

Comment: The divs turned into one column when I add `clear: left;`